# Why child component doesn't get updated in components tree?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to pass state to the child, to update the list of objects.
When I add an entry, it's not rendered in the child component. 
I also checked that `state.contacts` actually gets replaced with new array, but it didn't work.

```
  constructor(props) {
    this.super(props);
  }

  removeContact(event) {
    this.setState((state) => {
      state.contacts = state.contacts.filter((contact) => contact.key !== event.target.key )
      return state;
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <span>{this.props.contact.name}</span>
        <span>{this.props.contact.phone}</span>
        <span>{this.props.contact.adress}</span>
        <a href="#" onClick={this.removeContact}>X</a>
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

class Contacts extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { contacts: props.contacts };
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.contacts); // always displays empty array
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.contacts.map((contact, index) => 
          <div>
            <Contact key={index} contact={contact} contacts={this.state.contacts}/>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    time: new Date(),
    name: "",
    phone: "",
    adress: "",
    contacts: []
  }

  change = (event) => {
    let nameOfField = event.target.name;

    this.setState({[nameOfField]: event.target.value})
  }

  // click = () => { 
  //   this.setState((state) => {
  //     state.time = new Date();
  //     return state;
  //   })
  // }

  addContact = () => {
    let name = this.state.name;
    let phone = this.state.phone;
    let adress = this.state.adress;

    this.setState((state) => {
      return {contacts: [ ... state.contacts.concat([{name, adress, phone}])]}
    });

  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div className="App">
      <Timestamp time={this.state.time}/>
      <Contacts contacts={this.state.contacts}/>
      <input name="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.change} placeholder="Name"/>
      <input name="phone" value={this.state.phone} onChange={this.change} placeholder="Phone"/>
      <input name="adress" value={this.state.adress} onChange={this.change} placeholder="Adress"/>
      <button onClick={this.addContact}>Add contact</button>
    </div> 
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App time={Date.now().toString()}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 2):

If values are *passed* to Components you should render them as `props`.  There is no need to copy into the child component state:

```
class Contacts extends Component {

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.contacts); // use props instead of state
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.contacts.map((contact, index) => 
          <div>
            <Contact key={index} contact={contact} contacts={this.props.contacts}/>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Using `this.props` is good practice because it allows React to *deterministically* render (If the same props are passed, the same render result is returned).

Answer (score 2):

You are currently modifying the state in `Contacts` from it's child component `Contact`. You can't update a parents state directly from within a child component.

What you could do is create a `removeContact` function in your `Contacts` component and pass the entire function down to your `Contact` component. That way when you call `removeContact` in your child component, it will actually call it from the parent, modify the parents state, and update all it's children with the new state.